# pass multiple flash warning message with laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, flash-message

Laravel can only show one message by type of messages (danger, warning, success, info).
There is a solution for passing many warning message (for example) :

In the controller send a tab :

```
$messagesSuccess = [
    'test success 1',
    'test success 2'
];
$messagesInfo = [
    'test info 1',
    'test info 2'
];

$messagesWarning = [
    'test warning 1',
    'test warning 2'
];

$messagesError = [
    'test error 1',
    'test error 2'
];

$request->session ()->flash ( 'alert-info', $messagesInfo );
$request->session ()->flash ( 'alert-success', $messagesSuccess );
$request->session ()->flash ( 'alert-warning', $messagesWarning );
$request->session ()->flash ( 'alert-danger', $messagesError );
```

And in the php view :

```
            <div class="flash-message">
            <ul>
                @foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $type_message)
                    @if(Session::has('alert-' . $type_message))
                        @foreach (Session::get('alert-' . $type_message) as $message)
                        <li><p class="alert alert-{{ $type_message }}">{{ $message }}</p></li>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        @endif <!-- end .flash-message -->
```

An example of the css :

```
.flash-message {
    border-width: 0.2 em;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: grey;
}

.alert {
    font-size: 1 em;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.alert-danger {
    color : #ff6c00;
}

.alert-warning {
    color : #FFD700;
}

.alert-success {
    color : green;
}

.alert-info {
    color : blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old message, - but I just asked a similar question and got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53454932/notifications-in-laravel-stored-in-session-how-to-create-and-clear-them).

If I understand it correctly, then the key (the first parameter of `flash()`) is just used to tell where the message comes from. The second parameter kan be an array, and that can the contain the things you need to display the message correctly. I (for instance) have a flash-message like this:

```
session()->flash( 'file_was_not_readable', [
   'title'   => 'Error reading uploaded file'
   'message' => 'Blah di ba doo baa, di ba dee daa'
   'type'    => 'warning', 
  ]);
```

Comment: But this does not allow add message from other place in the code.